# lvalue required error while compiling

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct

```
 typedef struct _scaffale {
     int NumeroScaffale;
     scaffali * succ;
     copia** pos;
 } scaffale;
```

in which I have an array of the struct copia. The error comes in the following code:

```
copia** temp;
temp=scaff->pos;
(temp+controllo)=nuovo->copie;
```

in the third row to be precise. The question is: why this line give me that error while in the following code in which I use the same construct it is perfectly allowed:

```
while(i<=MAXLIBRI){
    if ((temp+i)!=NULL) {
        i=i+1;
    }
    else break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(temp+controllo)` is an rvalue. By that I mean it's a computed value, not a location to put something. I'm guessing that what you really meant is `*(temp+controllo) = nuovo->copie;` instead, which would have assigned `nuovo->copie` into the location identified by `temp+controllo`.

For an analogy, if `i` is an `int`, you can say `i = 3`, but you can't say `(i+1) = 3`. I hope it's obvious why.

Comment: very well.. just a forgetfulness.. thank you very much for such quick answer.

Comment: Also, instead of `*(temp + controllo)`, use `temp[controllo]`.

Answer (score 2):

`(temp+controllo)` is a computed value, and doesn't follow the language rules for being a proper `l-value` which is a fancy way of saying "you can't put it on the left of an assignment operator".

Comment: The `temp += controllo` line is completely pointless in this code.

Comment: Also, lvalue != can be assigned. An array is an lvalue, yet it can't be assigned.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: No, `array = 5` does not work. It's a hard error.

Comment: my mistake.  Thank you for pointing it out.  I'm probably reminiscing the ghosts of array* and array[0] compatibility.